# how to assign categorical values according to numbers in a column of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

I have a data frame with a column 'score'. It contains scores from 1 to 10. I want to create a new column "color" which gives the column color according to the score.

For e.g. if the score is 1, the value of color should be "#75968f", if the score is 2, the value of color should be "#a5bab7". i.e. we need colors ["#75968f", "#a5bab7", "#c9d9d3", "#e2e2e2","#f1d4Af", "#dfccce", "#ddb7b1", "#cc7878", "#933b41", "#550b1d"] for scores [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] respectively.

Is it possible to do this without using a loop?
Let me know in case you have a problem understanding the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with dictionary generated by zipping both lists or if need range by length of list `colors` is possible use `enumerate`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'score':[2,4,6,3,8]})

colors = ["#75968f", "#a5bab7", "#c9d9d3", "#e2e2e2","#f1d4Af", 
          "#dfccce", "#ddb7b1", "#cc7878", "#933b41", "#550b1d"]
scores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

df['new'] = df['score'].map(dict(zip(scores, colors))) 

df['new1'] = df['score'].map(dict(enumerate(colors, 1)))   
print (df)
   score      new     new1
0      2  #a5bab7  #a5bab7
1      4  #e2e2e2  #e2e2e2
2      6  #dfccce  #dfccce
3      3  #c9d9d3  #c9d9d3
4      8  #cc7878  #cc7878
```